# second order differential equation $xy^n + 2\frac{dy}{dx} = 12x^2$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$xy^n + 2\frac{dy}{dx} = 12x^2$

Solve the second-order diﬀerential equation
by making the substitution $u = \frac{dy}{dx} $

this is the question.

I tried to solve it using the integration factor. But since it has a $y^n$ in i can't figure it out.

They do say solve the second order differential equation does this mean that since it is second order that $y$ should equeal $2$? 
Should i use the integration factor or use a different technique?
I also dont get how substituting $u$ for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ would do anything.

Comment: is it a second order differential equation ? IS there a typo ?

Comment: just to make sure; the $\frac{dx}{dy}$ in the equation is intended? not $\frac{dy}{dx}$?

Comment: @StijnDietz it's Bernouilli's equation in x...but op mention a substitution for a second order differential equation

Comment: @Isham I see now

Comment: yes it should be $\frac{dy}{dx}$

Comment: no typo, it says second-order differential equation.

Comment: The problem is the $y^n$ term which is a misprint or a faulty transmission from some hand-written (probably very curvy) $y''=\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$. Without that change, your equation is first order, not second order. With the change it can be compacted to $(x^2y')'=12x^3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several indication that the original problem was
$$
xy''+2y'=12x^2,
$$
not the least because then the factor $12$ allows for a "nice" (with simple coefficients/constants) solution
$$
 y=x^3+\frac{c}x+d.
$$

At some point the superscript in $y''$ was mis-interpreted as the similar looking $n$.

Comment: i carefully looked at the question again and indeed it is a double accent and not an n. this makes it a lot easier to solve thanks